# Solving recurrence with asymptotic

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

Consider some increasing, integer valued, function $f$ defined on the integers, such that $f(n)=\Theta(n\log n)$ when $n\to\infty$. For every $n$, let $g(n)=\inf\{k\mid f(k)\geqslant n\}$.

Now, for each $u_0$, define $(u_n)$ recursively by $u_{n+1}=g(u_n)$ for every $n$ and define $N(u_0)$ as the smallest $n$ such that $u_n\leqslant1$.

> What are the asymptotics of $N(u_0)$ when $u_0\to\infty$?

My hope is that $N(n)=\Theta\left(\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}\right)$.

Comment: What is the meaning of "$u_i$ minimizes $f(u_i)$" ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust $u_i$ is a positive integer which minimizes an expression in $u_i$. For instance $f(u_i)$ could be $\sum_{i=2}^{u_i} \log i$.

Comment: At present, one cannot decipher your question. If, as I suspect, you have a specific setting in mind, from which you tried to extrapolate a general question, you might want to do quite the opposite and to explain in details the specific situation.

Comment: @Did Thank you for your remark. I have updated my question. Do you suggest I write an example of function for $f$?

Comment: Anything that can help us understand what you mean, really. For example... Assume that $f$ is increasing, then is your definition stating that $$u_i=f^{-1}(u_{i-1})\ ?$$

Comment: @Did $f(u_i)$ could be  $\sum_{i=2}^{u_i} \log i$. It is not invertible but we have the asymptotic approximation I have given.

Comment: @Did  I have updated the post by adding more information

Comment: I added a reformulation of your question, according to what I understand you wish to be asking. Is it correct? (Note that you will have to make up your mind about imposing or not, that $f$ is increasing.)

Comment: @Did Thank you very much for your formulation. This is exactly that! I remove the first part of the question.

Comment: Then, roughly speaking, the function $N$ solves $N(n\log n)=N(n)+1$ when $n$ is large. Now, if $N(n)=\log n$ then $N(n\log n)-N(n)\to\infty$ while, if $N(n)=(\log n)^a$ for some $a<1$ then $N(n\log n)-N(n)\to0$. Thus, one can expect that $N(n)$ grows like $\log n$, up to some sub-logarithmic correction terms.

Comment: @Did Thank you for your help. I fact, I was hoping that $N(n)$ grows like $\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}$.

Comment: @Did Why $N(n\log n)-N(n)\to\infty$ when $N(n\log n)=N(n)+1$?

Comment: You misread what I wrote: **IF** $N(n)=\log n$ **THEN** $N(n\log n)-N(n)=\log\log n$ hence indeed $N(n\log n)-N(n)\to\infty$. // Note that $\log\log n$ corresponds exactly to some "sub-logarithmic correction term" to the main term $\log n$ that I am mentioning in my previous comment, hence your predictions correspond to mine.

Comment: @Did Thank you, I understand. So, is it sufficient to prove that $N(n\log n)=N(n)+1$?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**:

You can't answer, the asymptotic expression gives no clue about the initial values of $u$. $k$ could be $1$ and up to $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks @YvesDaoust I do not understand. The initial value is $u_0$.

Comment: @Dingo13: is said value**s**. $f(u_1)$ could be $10^{100}$.

Comment: Thank you. I update my post. The values $u_2$, $u_3$ are obtained by solving the same optimization problem.